# Manipulating Paths in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, filepath

Currently, I have some view paths in an array, which are then required, but I would like to automatically scan the directory and subdirectories for folders:

```
paths = ['a/', 'b/', 'c/', 'd/d2/', '']
for path in paths
    try
        View = require(path+name)
    catch e
        lastError = e
if View
    return View
else
    throw lastError
```

I tried the following but it seems I can't use the File class:

```
paths = []
clientPath = __dirname.replace('/base', '') # go up a directory
currentFiles = []
currentFiles = fs.readdirSync(clientPath)
for file in currentFiles
    checkFile = new File(clientPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()
    if checkFile
        paths.push(file + "/")
```

What is a good way to manipulate path strings in Backbone?

Answer (score 0):

If this code is running in the browser, you're out of luck. JavaScript running in a browser [doesn't have access to the filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security) for security reasons, so you can't require your files this way.

The good news is that [Require.js includes an optimiser that will compile your requirements for you](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). You could also use something like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with a [Require.js plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) to accomplish this build step too.